# Email not sending from admin in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, email, email-templates, email-translation

If I can place an order from the frontend, then the order email was sent successfully.

But in the admin side, (Invoice, shipment, notify, send email) Email is not sending in live.

But both side email is sending in local.

How to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried sending a blank mail just to test ??

Comment: If I click 'Send Email' option in view order. It is not working

Comment: @ManoM first check your server in email service is working or not

Comment: I placed an order from the frontend, then the order email was sent successfully.